# Heroku Node.js version 16

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord, discord.js

I'm currently trying to run a Discord bot using discord.js version 13, but that requires Node.js version 16. Heroku only uses Node.js 14.

How can I update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Heroku only uses Node.js 14

Where did you get that idea?

At the time of writing, [Heroku supports Node.js versions 12.x, 14.x, and 16.x](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#supported-runtimes). You can [specify the version you want via the `engines` key in your `package.json`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version), like in this slightly modified example from the docs:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "description": "a really cool app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  }
}
```

Make sure you update your local version of Node.js, too.

I'm not sure what operating system you are using, but I usually use [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to manager multiple versions of Node.js on one machine.